# Easiest possible certificate key for Android App

Tags: android

How "easy" can an e.g. RSA key for Android get? The lowest I've got was 512, with `keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias b -keyalg RSA -keysize 512 -validity 1`

256 won't work because of how RSA is build up but are there other algorithms I could insert before `-keysize` as parameter? I was able to create a 256 bit long with EC but unfortunately, android won't accept this one as it throws "Failed to seal APK" at export.

// Please don't be that guy who screams "this is not programming related", because I really think it is and maybe someone comes up with an algorithm to create my key of desire :)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. What do you mean by "easy"?

Since the 512-bit RSA key is apparently working for you, what is it that you would like to do differently?

Comment: "easy" in terms of "less difficult to hack", I just wanna play around without having a supercomputer

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of the Android documentation specify SHA1withRSA or SHA256withRSA

Not sure if either of those still work - why not try it and let us know?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried both already but the "tail" of the file still persists EDIT I mean "tail" in terms of "extensions:"...